# How to call function only defined in .c file properly? (kernel development)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Recently I try to modify some code in linux kernel and my goal is to add customize [vdso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO).

In my plan, both `update_vdso_data` (function in `kernel/time/vsyscall.c`) and `vepoll_reg.c` ( my new vdso implementation under `arch/x86/entry/vdso/` ) will call function defined in `fs/eventpoll.c`. I didn't find any header defined function I needed in `eventpoll.c`, as a result, I just include .c file in them and didn't modify `makefile`.

When I build the kernel, their came up a lot of warning and error messages.

```
  CC      kernel/time/vsyscall.o
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:94,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:13,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:65,
                 from ./include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:73,
                 from ./include/linux/ktime.h:24,
                 from ./include/linux/hrtimer_defs.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/hrtimer.h:15,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/vdso/vsyscall.h:7,
                 from ./include/vdso/vsyscall.h:7,
                 from arch/x86/entry/vdso/vepoll_reg.c:2:
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h: In function ‘ep_remove’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:539:3: warning: asm operand 3 probably doesn’t match constraints
  539 |   asm volatile(pre     \
      |   ^~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:555:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘____PVOP_VCALL’
  555 |  ____PVOP_VCALL(op.func, CLBR_RET_REG,    \
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:580:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘__PVOP_VCALLEESAVE’
  580 |  __PVOP_VCALLEESAVE(op, "", "", PVOP_CALL_ARG1(arg1))
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:559:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘PVOP_VCALLEE1’
  559 |  PVOP_VCALLEE1(lock.queued_spin_unlock, lock);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:539:3: warning: asm operand 3 probably doesn’t match constraints
  539 |   asm volatile(pre     \
      |   ^~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:555:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘____PVOP_VCALL’
  555 |  ____PVOP_VCALL(op.func, CLBR_RET_REG,    \
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:569:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘__PVOP_VCALLEESAVE’
  569 |  __PVOP_VCALLEESAVE(op, "", "")
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:663:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘PVOP_VCALLEE0’
  663 |  PVOP_VCALLEE0(irq.irq_enable);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:539:3: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
  539 |   asm volatile(pre     \
      |   ^~~
```

I guess this is the result I include file improperly. My question is that are there better ways to call function which didn't defined in .h file?

Comment: "ways to call function which didn't defined in .h file?" - You may create a header which **declares** the function (specifies its signature), or you may just **declare** the function in your source file (where you use the function). Make sure that function **definition** is not "static". Including a `.c` file is almost never a good way.

Comment: What if the function I need is static?

Comment: In that case you need to remove "static" specifier.